# omniauthとdeviseでGoogleAPIのユーザー認証時に、クライアントIDが見つからないとエラーが出る

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

#### 前提・実現したいこと

railsでTwitter型WEBサービスを制作しています。
deviseとomniauthでgoogle認証できるようにしたいのですが、Google
側から「クライアントIDが見つからない」と怒られてしまいます
主に参考にしたページはこちらです

[deviseとomniauthを使ったGoogle認証の流れ-in Qiita](https://qiita.com/s-show/items/9de77de4eb480f779aa4)

[googleからのログイン実装-in Qiita](https://qiita.com/ttaka66/items/9ea3052a6f17a0b8f5fc)

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

写真のようにError: invalid_request
Missing required parameter: client_idと表示されてしまいます。

```
![Google認証リンク先](233d78ac7bf108c9c958f8cb1ba390f6.png)
```

#### 該当のソースコード

Gemfile

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'


#easy test
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.6'
  gem "capybara"

end
# meke user administor
gem 'rails_admin'
# easier form create
gem 'simple_form'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'
# image upload
gem 'carrierwave'
# make easier restigation and login 
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
#user admin gem
gem 'cancancan'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
```

/model/User.rb

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,:omniauthable

  def self.find_for_google_oauth2(auth)
  user = User.where(email: auth.info.email).first
  unless user
  user = User.create(name:     auth.info.name,
                     provider: auth.provider,
                     uid:      auth.uid,
                     email:    auth.info.email,
                     token:    auth.credentials.token,
                     password: Devise.friendly_token[0, 20])
  end
  user
  end
  def remember_me
    true
  end
end
```

/config/initializer/devise.rb

```rb
  # so you need to do it manually. For the users scope, it would be:
  # config.omniauth_path_prefix = '/my_engine/users/auth'

  # ==> Turbolinks configuration
  # If your app is using Turbolinks, Turbolinks::Controller needs to be included to make redirection work correctly:
  #
  # ActiveSupport.on_load(:devise_failure_app) do
  #   include Turbolinks::Controller
  # end

  # ==> Configuration for :registerable

  # When set to false, does not sign a user in automatically after their password is
  # changed. Defaults to true, so a user is signed in automatically after changing a password.
  # config.sign_in_after_change_password = true
  config.omniauth :google_oauth2,Rails.application.secrets.google_client_id,Rails.application.secrets.google_client_secret
end
```

/config/initializer/omniauth.rb

```rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2,
    Rails.application.secrets.google_client_id,
    Rails.application.secrets.google_client_secret,
    {
# ログイン後にGoogle Calendarのデータを取得したいので、scopeに
# https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendarを記述しています。
# また、promptとaccess_typeを以下の設定にするとrefresh_tokenが得られる
# （その他の組み合わせは試していません）。
      scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,
              https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile,
              https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
      prompt: "select_account",
      access_type: "offline"
    }

end
```

/config/secrets.yml

```rb
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Your secret key is used for verifying the integrity of signed cookies.
# If you change this key, all old signed cookies will become invalid!

# Make sure the secret is at least 30 characters and all random,
# no regular words or you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.
# You can use `rails secret` to generate a secure secret key.

# Make sure the secrets in this file are kept private
# if you're sharing your code publicly.

development:
  secret_key_base: 77c01ff0bf353d58ef52fc73e2707886ed0b5218cd057fcb7a4404702406cc87bd6fe482f68103fc35377dadfc3fec6550df0e1fb29e941134e1f5958e561c95

test:
  secret_key_base: 5124f54d8a7cb1113e4aa5ae65994ea0a0d5c73d2971c082fb9d44e1b2d2219e8c0f0f77181662084df44cd66f3e9c42db9494642ea57060c1026ad4f410d62c

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
#idとシークレットは質問用に改変しています
google_client_id: 240395658877-np5n29adf9gn3jjn88awdawdawv9gu84pl4p.apps.googleusercontent.com
google_client_secret: hAIRJiARkDFB6vGNadawdB04W
```

app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```rb
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def google_oauth2
    @user = User.find_for_google_oauth2(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    # 保存済みかどうかのチェック
    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

/config/routes

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get '/about'=>'static_pages#about'

    devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: 'users/registrations',
    sessions: "users/sessions",
    omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks",
  }

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

#### 試したこと

↓の記事を参考にしました。figaroというgemを使って環境変数にクライアントIDを定義するという方法だったのですが、記事は本番環境を想定していて、開発環境下の自分が同じ操作をしてよいものかわからず、保留しています
[figaroを使って環境変数にクライアントIDを定義する](https://codeday.me/jp/qa/20190710/1218299.html)
複数ユーザーでログインしていると重複リダイレクトで上記のようなエラーが出るという記事（記事のurlは忘れてしまいました）を見て、ほかのユーザーをログアウトしてみたのですが、結果は同じでした。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

cloud9使用
Rails 5.0.7.2

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/202873

Answer (score 0):

以下の問題がありそうです。

- config/initializers/devise.rb の "s" が抜けている
- Deviseを使用する場合の設定と、使用しない場合の設定が混在している

[公式のREADMEのDeviseの項](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2#devise) に、以下の記載があります。

> First define your application id and secret in config/initializers/devise.rb. Do not use the snippet mentioned in the Usage section.
>   （中略）
>   NOTE: If you are using this gem with devise with above snippet in config/initializers/devise.rb then do not create config/initializers/omniauth.rb which will conflict with devise configurations.

Deviseを使用する場合は、config/initializers/devise.rb に必要な設定を記載し、 config/initializers/omniauth.rb は作成しないでくださいとのことです。

まだ解決されていないようでしたらお試しください。